# user friendly SEO in angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, .htaccess

I was able to remove # from the url but when the page reload it goes to 404 
i have added this to app.js:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

and this to index.html

```
<base href="/lawyer/">
```

and also created .htacces file and added this to it

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}          
!^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     .               /index.html              [L]
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Still not able to make the urls user friendly? and still  when I refresh the page IT GOES TO 404

Comment: How are your urls now? And how do you want them to be? That would really help to come up with a solution...

Comment: Right now they are:localhost/myproject/#/home and i want them to be localhost/myproject/home

Comment: Have you read, understood and implemented https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode?

Comment: If you go directly to `localhost/myproject/home` after making your changes, what happens? Also is your main file `index.html` or `index.php`?

Comment: Its index.html and when I reload page it goes to 404